# MongoEngine changing default parameter "required" value

Tags: python, mongoengine

I wonder if there is a possibility of changing default value of the "required" parameter for all fields.

Almost all the fields of my models are required and so I have to put the parameter `required=True` for almost all the fields, it's a little painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own Field classes. For example:

```
from mongoengine import fields


class StringField(fields.StringField):
    def __init__(self, regex=None, max_length=None, min_length=None, default=True, **kwargs):
        super(StringField, self).__init__(regex, max_length, min_length, default=default, **kwargs)
```

That will allow you to have a StringField class that has the default value of `required` set to `True`. Unfortunately you have to do that for every Field class that you use.